# Calculating the probability of selecting the same character T times in a row from N discrete distributions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a sequence $P$ of $N$ probability distributions over an alphabet $A$, I want to produce a string $S$ of length $N$ where the $i^{th}$ character is drawn from the $i^{th}$ probability distribution.

$$S_i = A[P_{i}(X)]$$

How can I calculate the probability of my output string containing a substring consisting of the same (specific) character T times in a row?

For the question of non-repeating character substrings I believe I can multiply the probabilities of *not* finding my substring at each index, then subtract the resulting value from 1 to find the probability that I *do* find the substring somewhere.

However, this does not work for repeated characters. As a simple example, consider the alphabet $A = \{a,b\}$ and the following distributions:
$$P_1 = (1.0, 0.0)$$
$$P_2 = (0.5, 0.5)$$
$$P_3 = (1.0, 0.0)$$

I want to know the probability of my output string containing the substring $aa$. Carrying out the above procedure would give me a probability of $0.75$ of finding an $aa$ substring, but clearly the correct likelihood is $0.5$ as there are only two possible outcomes: $\{aaa, aba\}$. The issue seems to be that I'm effectively "double counting", since the middle character has a 50% chance of being an $a$, and thus counts as contributing to an $aa$ substring with the 1st and 3rd character.

Comment: The issue is not double counting but dependence. Specifically, the event that the first two characters are "aa" and the event that the latter two characters are "aa" are not independent.

Comment: Seemingly you are familiar with coding, then maybe you can see the intuitive from the KMP algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ with $|A| = n$.
Seemingly you are familiar with programming. We would use an interactive formula, and a similar idea is used in "dynamic programming".

For simplicity, let's say we want to know whether the random string contains "$a_1a_1a_1\ldots a_1$" ($T$ times).
Let us maintain a vector $P = (p_0, p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_T)$, where $p_j$ represents the probability that **at the current position we have $j$ consecutive $a_1$**.
Specially, $p_T$ also includes the probability that there are already $T$ consecutive $a_1$ before the current position.
After all updates, $p_T$ would be the desired probability that we want to compute.

Initialization: $P = (1, 0,0,\ldots,0)$.

At each position $i = 1,2,3,\ldots,N$, we do the following update:

- with probability $\Pr[S_i = a_1]$, we would have a new $a_1$ at the current position
- with probability $1 - \Pr[S_i = a_1]$, we would have zero $a_1$ at the current position

Therefore, we have
$$p_0 \leftarrow (1 - p_T) (1 - \Pr[S_i = a_1])$$
$$p_j \leftarrow p_{j-1} \Pr[S_i = a_1], \forall 1 \leq j < T$$
$$p_T \leftarrow p_T + p_{T-1} \Pr[S_i = a_1]$$

It is easy to check that if the previous $P$ sums up to one, then the updated $P$ also does.

Comment: Thank you! This solution is very helpful. It might be worth noting that you cannot update $P$ in-place without running the algorithm in reverse (starting from T and working backward to 0), otherwise values from the previous iteration are overwritten too early. I'm curious: Does this generalize to the case of non-repeating characters (i.e. arbitrary substrings) if we calculate $Pr[S_i = a_i]$ instead of always checking for $a_1$ explicitly?

Comment: I suppose unfortunately it doesn't directly translate. I was hoping to avoid special casing repeated sequence targets vs. non-repeating targets.